# Geo-Search (Distance) in PHP/MySQL (Performance)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, distance, gis

I have a MySQL-table (MyISAM) containing about 200k entries of lat/long pairs that I select from, based on the pairs distance (great circle formula) from another lat/long pair. (e.g. all entries that are within a 10km radius around 50.281852, 2.504883)

My problem is that this query takes about 0,28 sec. to run just for those 200k entries (which continue to get more every day). While 0,28 sec. would be fine normally, this query runs very often as it powers the main feature of my web-app, and often times it's part of a larger query.

Is there any way to speed this up? Obviously MySQL has to run through all 200k entries every time and perform the great circle formula for every entry. I read something about geohashing, R-Trees and the like here on Stack Overflow but I don't think that's the way I want to go. Partly because I've never been a big fan of maths, but mostly because I think that this problem has already been solved by someone smarter than me in a library/extension/etc. that has been tested extensively and is being updated regularly.

MySQL seems to have a spatial extension but that one doesn't provide a distance function. Should I be looking at another database to put this coordinate-pairs in? PostgreSQL seems to have a fairly mature Spatial extension. Do you know anything about it? Or would PostgreSQL too simply just use the great circle formula to get all entries within a certain region?

Is there maybe a specialized stand-alone product or mysql-extension that already does what I'm looking for?

Or is there maybe A PHP library I could use to do the calculations? Using APC I could easily fit the lat-long pairs into memory (those 200k entries take about 5MB) and then run the query inside of PHP. The problem with this approach however is that then I'd have a MySQL query like SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE id in (id1, id2, ..) for all the results which can be up to a few thousand. How well does MySQL handle Queries like these? And then (since this is a number-crunching task) would doing this in PHP be fast enough?

Any other Ideas what I should/shouldn't do?

For completeness, here is the sample query, stripped of any irrelevant parts (as I said, usually this is part of a bigger query where I join multiple tables):

```sql
SELECT id,
       6371 * acos( sin( radians( 52.4042924 ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) + cos( radians( 50.281852 ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( 2.504883 ) - radians( lon ) ) ) AS dst
FROM geoloc
HAVING dst <10
ORDER BY dst ASC
```

Comment: When searching inside a radius (distance) of only 10 miles (15 km), can't you just leave out the whole curvature equation and equate for a circle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calculate a bounding box to select a subset of the rows in the WHERE clause of your SQL query, so that you're only executing the expensive distance calculation on that subset of rows rather than against the entire 200k records in your table. The method is described in this [article on Movable Type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) (with PHP code examples). Then you can include the Haversine calculation in your query against that subset to calculate the actual distances, and factor in the HAVING clause at that point.

It's the bounding box that helps your performance, because it means you're only doing the expensive distance calculation on a small subset of your data. This is effectively the same method that Patrick has suggested, but the Movable Type link has extensive explanations of the method, as well as PHP code that you can use to build the bounding box and your SQL query.

**EDIT**

If you don't think haversine is accurate enough, then there's also the Vincenty formula.

```
//  Vincenty formula to calculate great circle distance between 2 locations expressed as Lat/Long in KM

function VincentyDistance($lat1,$lat2,$lon1,$lon2){
    $a = 6378137 - 21 * sin($lat1);
    $b = 6356752.3142;
    $f = 1/298.257223563;

    $p1_lat = $lat1/57.29577951;
    $p2_lat = $lat2/57.29577951;
    $p1_lon = $lon1/57.29577951;
    $p2_lon = $lon2/57.29577951;

    $L = $p2_lon - $p1_lon;

    $U1 = atan((1-$f) * tan($p1_lat));
    $U2 = atan((1-$f) * tan($p2_lat));

    $sinU1 = sin($U1);
    $cosU1 = cos($U1);
    $sinU2 = sin($U2);
    $cosU2 = cos($U2);

    $lambda = $L;
    $lambdaP = 2*M_PI;
    $iterLimit = 20;

    while(abs($lambda-$lambdaP) > 1e-12 && $iterLimit>0) {
        $sinLambda = sin($lambda);
        $cosLambda = cos($lambda);
        $sinSigma = sqrt(($cosU2*$sinLambda) * ($cosU2*$sinLambda) + ($cosU1*$sinU2-$sinU1*$cosU2*$cosLambda) * ($cosU1*$sinU2-$sinU1*$cosU2*$cosLambda));

        //if ($sinSigma==0){return 0;}  // co-incident points
        $cosSigma = $sinU1*$sinU2 + $cosU1*$cosU2*$cosLambda;
        $sigma = atan2($sinSigma, $cosSigma);
        $alpha = asin($cosU1 * $cosU2 * $sinLambda / $sinSigma);
        $cosSqAlpha = cos($alpha) * cos($alpha);
        $cos2SigmaM = $cosSigma - 2*$sinU1*$sinU2/$cosSqAlpha;
        $C = $f/16*$cosSqAlpha*(4+$f*(4-3*$cosSqAlpha));
        $lambdaP = $lambda;
        $lambda = $L + (1-$C) * $f * sin($alpha) * ($sigma + $C*$sinSigma*($cos2SigmaM+$C*$cosSigma*(-1+2*$cos2SigmaM*$cos2SigmaM)));
    }

    $uSq = $cosSqAlpha*($a*$a-$b*$b)/($b*$b);
    $A = 1 + $uSq/16384*(4096+$uSq*(-768+$uSq*(320-175*$uSq)));
    $B = $uSq/1024 * (256+$uSq*(-128+$uSq*(74-47*$uSq)));

    $deltaSigma = $B*$sinSigma*($cos2SigmaM+$B/4*($cosSigma*(-1+2*$cos2SigmaM*$cos2SigmaM)- $B/6*$cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*$sinSigma*$sinSigma)*(-3+4*$cos2SigmaM*$cos2SigmaM)));

    $s = $b*$A*($sigma-$deltaSigma);
    return $s/1000;
}


echo VincentyDistance($lat1,$lat2,$lon1,$lon2);
```

Comment: @epitaph - If you're using a bounding box with a WHERE clause that filters out records with a Lat/Long that are clearly out of range (particularly if you have an index on lat/long), then you're selecting based on the bounding box __before__ doing any Haversine/Vincenty/distance calculation... so you're not calculating distance for 200k records, just for the subset that fall within the bounding box. And if you try testing it, that makes it very noticeably faster.

Comment: Which lat is in the first line? $lat1 or $lat2?

Comment: fyi: The PI is undefined, I used [pi()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php)

Comment: Would somebody care to explain the recent downvotes for a perfectly valid answer, unless it's Phpdna.... in which case I know that he'll downvote anybody answering a geospatial or distance related question that doesn't point people to his quadkey library

Comment: @PHPDNA - Well perhaps your own answer should actually explain what quadtrees are and why they're so fast, and perhaps even how to use them rather than simply saying "my library is cool cos it uses stuff that you couldn't possibly understand".... perhaps then you'd get the upvotes and wouldn't feel this urgent need to assert your intellectual superiority by downvoting any answer that isn't as l33t as yours

Comment: @PHPDna - I post it because its easy for people to understand. I don't try to bedazzle people with quadtrees and Hilbert curves and moore curves and other jargon that they won't understand... I post it with a basic explanation of how it works... I post it because I can post actual working code rather than point people to a library on a site where they need to register to even see your code.... and I don't go round systematically downvoting the answers of other people who don't agree with me

Comment: My answer __does__ answer the OPs question... it shows a way of reducing the number of rows retrieved by a SQL query that will make it faster to search through 200k entries __without__ needing to load every entry into a quadtree in PHP memory.... that's a valid answer to the question; and though it may not be the only answer to the OP's it's factually correct.... And PHPClasses is alright if you want to register with them (though there's a lot of badly-written libraries there as well as good libraries), but not everybody does want to register with a new site to get an answer to their questions

Comment: I understand how quadtrees work, I'm writing a C implementation for SPL at the moment, and it don't even use arrays of any dimension... just pointers to null or to the NW/SW/NE/SE nodes in the tree. Search is fast, but populating the quadtree is slower... especially with large volumes of data when you have to populate the entire quadtree before using it

Comment: No, I mean PHP's SPL ([Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)), specifically the [datastructures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php). I'm currently working on SPLTrie and SPLQuadTree

Comment: You need C because PHP itself is written in C. What I'm doing is writing new datastructures __for__ PHP itself, not writing datastructures __in__ PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker: who are you arguing with ? I don't see any 'epitaph' answering you :P. Care to comment on my answer please ?

Comment: @kellogs - Epitaph or PHPDna (or whatever name he's using this week) has a tendency to downvote any answer to a geospatial question that doesn't use his hilbertcurve solution as found on PHPClasses, and never explains how it works or why it's a better solution when he does answer questions; and when he does deign to respond in comments he has this annoying tendency to delete them again after he knows they've been read

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but what i the bounding box contains 200k entries? The problem would remain the same. Been looking through alot of answers to simliar problems everyone suggest this solution, but nobody takes into case that the bounding box can actually contain alot of results.

Comment: If it's 200k entries, then you're using a badly sized bounding box. Using geospatial-aware databases is better for performance anyway (epecially in 2017); but it's also possible to create summary tables to identify the number of points in a "grid" segment, and that can give you an idea of whether your bounding box is sensibly sized or not; or alternative datastructures such as quadtrees, which are far more efficient for retrieving datapoints within an area

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for your answer Mark, I will research your pointers and look into it! cheers

Answer (score 15):

What if you approach the problem from a different angle?

10 km in a straight line is:

1. on the latitude is equal to ~1'(minute)
2. on the longitude is equal to ~6'(minutes)

Using this as a basis, do some quick math and in your query add to the `WHERE` clause removing any locations that are outside the 'box' that is created by adding the buffer zone with the assumption of 1' lat & 6' long

[image: gps buffer zone circle]

Working from this image:

1. GPS location you are searching for (34° 12' 34.0", -85° 1' 1.0") [34.2094444444, -85.0169444444]
2. You find the min/max latitude/longitude

   2a.  Min Latitude  - 34.1927777778, -85.0169444444

   2b.  Min Longitude - 34.2094444444, -85.1169444444

   2c.  Max Latitude  - 34.2261111111, -85.0169444444

   2d.  Max Longitude - 34.2094444444, -84.9169444444
3. Run your query with the min and max of each direction

   ```
   SELECT *

   FROM geoloc

   WHERE

   lat >= 34.1927777 AND

   lat <= 34.2261111 AND

   long >= -85.1169444 AND

   long <= -84.9169444;
   ```

You can either integrate the distance calculation with the SQL query or you can use a PHP library/class to run the distance check after pulling the data.  Either way you have reduced the number of calculations by a large percentage.

I use the following function to calculate the distance between two US84 GPS locations.  Two parameters are passed, each parameter is an array with the first element being the latitude and the second element being the longitude.  I believe it has an accuracy to a few feet, which should be enough for all but the hardest core GPS-ophiles.  Also, I believe this uses the Haversine distance formula.

$distance = calculateGPSDistance(array(34.32343, -86.342343), array(34.433223, -96.0032344));

```
function calculateGPSDistance($site1, $site2)
{
    $distance = 0;
    $earthMeanRadius = 2.0891 * pow(10, 7);

    $deltaLatitude = deg2rad($site2[0] - $site1[0]);
    $deltaLongitude = deg2rad($site2[1] - $site1[1]);
    $a = sin($deltaLatitude / 2) * sin($deltaLatitude / 2) + cos(deg2rad($site1[0])) * 
        cos(deg2rad($site2[0])) * sin($deltaLongitude / 2) * sin($deltaLongitude / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    $distance = $earthMeanRadius * $c;

    return $distance;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention, my distance function will return distance in feet.

Comment: does that work for europe? what is the difference between the haversine and the great circle formula?

Comment: @Bubbles yes this should work without problem in europe.  I believe the Haversine formula uses the great circle formula but from my experience it gives a more accurate distance in the real world.  You can read up about Haversine on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: @epitaph win? win or lose what? the OP is just trying to figure out a better way to make their website work.  sometimes the most computationally efficient algorithm is not the best.  ease of use & integration are important when updating code on a production site

Answer (score 0):

You could try a quadkey. It's a spatial index and reduce the dimension. It subdivide a map into tiles but you can use it to store points. You  can download my php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It also includes a z-curve and a moore-curve. Important is to know it uses a mercator projection. You can look for Bing maps tiling. It explains how to use a quadkey. You need x,y coordinate and z (zoom or depth) value. Then it gives you a quadkey.

Comment: I looket at your PHP code but I don't understand it. Do you have an example how you use it?

Comment: Not only is this answer written in poor English, it doesn't actually answer the question in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing till now is just as @Mark described above. A viable solution for small sites I guess, only not that good for my case (200k entries localized inside some 100x100 square km box centered around a given point. I was using this same trick of Mark's but performance is just too poor. 5 users/second querying for nearby lat/lon points for few hours and the queries start taking up to 10 - 15 seconds; and this happens *after* I have adjusted mySQL settings in my.cnf. Don't even want to think about what would happen when there will be 2 million entries worldwide.

So, now time for step 2: [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).
It should solve the problem of B-tree index on (lat, lon) columns which is wasteful (onrange scans, ony one part of the B-tree index is being used) by employing just one index on one column (hilbert_number). hilbert_number being a number calculated based on a point's lat/lon coordinates on the Hilbert curve.

But the second problem, of testing the distance between fixed point and everything from the previous result subset through the Haversine formula remains. That part can be very slow. So I was thinking about somehow testing for distance more directly, putting everything on the hilbert curve and applying some bitmask to that result subset instead of applying the Haversine formula. I just don't know how would I go about that...

Anyway, another trick I have employed to reduce the number of points in the result subset was to use two bounding boxes and include in the subset only the gray / white points for further Haversine testing:

[image: inner and outer BB]

What I need to do right now is switch to Hilbert numbers and see how it behaves. But I doubt this is going to increase 10x the performance!

Comment: I've been used a similar adjustment to the bounding box approach myself, starting with a small box query and then increasing outwards but adjusting the query so that previous results won't be returned again, multiple queries, but still fairly selective... as you say, it's fairly effective with small to moderate  data volumes, and more effective than a single bounding box. I prefer to use database geospatial extensions when they are built-in; but that isn't always an option, and the bounding box approach still works fairly well.

Comment: For large data volumes, I have been experimenting with quadtrees, and found them incredibly fast for the search, but expensively slow to load (and a memory hog for larger datasets). That's why I've been writing an extension for PHP to implement quadtrees as a C datastructure rather than a PHP datastructure... and is a lot more performant both for search and for the initial load than implementing the same in pure PHP

Comment: For large data volumes, I have been experimenting with quadtrees, and found them incredibly fast for search, but expensively slow to load (and a memory hog for larger datasets). That's why I've been writing an extension for PHP to implement quadtrees as a C datastructure rather than a PHP datastructure... and is a lot more performant both for search and for the initial load than implementing the same in pure PHP... but real benefits will come if I can serialize it so that it can be persisted in APC, memcached, redis or similar rather than having to be rebuilt from the db on every request

Comment: To an extent, it all depends on what question your query is trying to answer. If you want the list of all points within a certain radius of the centrepoint, you don't necessarily even need to calculate the actual distance for points within the inner bounding box (just the corners of the box itself), only for those points that lie between the inner and outer boxes to see whether they should be included or discarded; but if you want to order your list by distance, then you do need to calculate for all potential entries

Comment: Hmm, so I guess it should be fine with quadtrees in Java SE speed-wise ? Could you point me to a good tutorial on how to use quad trees for pseudocircular (and not pseudoBB) searches ? Preferably adapted to Hilbert curve; preferably already implemented in Java too :D