# Map web traffic (Google maps, BING maps, etc...)?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, mapping, ip, bing-maps

I'm capturing all the incoming ip's going to my website. I also have a web service that gets me the latitude and longitude for a given ip. I would now like to plot (using the lat & long) hundreds of thousands of points on a map to get a geographical over-view of where my traffic is coming from. Whats the best tool for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want a space-filling-curve if you want to speed up your massive query and I also I prefer Google Maps because it is fast and reliable and free.

Comment: any resources you can point me to that talk about using Google Maps & SFC?

Comment: Not really, I have wrote a sfc in php with z-curve, hilbert curve, moore curve and such but it is not yet finished but you want to search for nick's blog and spatial index hilbert curve quadtree!

Comment: FYI - using Google Maps and custom overlay: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#AddingOverlays

Comment: Thank you for voting! At the bottom of the page you will find my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236921/geo-search-distance-in-php-mysql-performance/5236997#5236997