# Geo Search Without Distance

Tags: php, geolocation, gis

This is my first look at geo location. Please forgive my long question. I hope it is clear.

I have a database holding records with lat & lng. I am trying to write a PHP class which defines four decimal coordinates that form a boundary box (to then retrieve all records within the box).

I only need to know which locations are within *n* km of the user location. I do not need the distances from the user to the locations.

I am building on the first part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237509/781200).

At the core of the above answer is:

> 10 km in a straight line is:
>
> ```
> on the latitude is equal to ~1'(minute)
> on the longitude is equal to ~6'(minutes)
> ```
>
> Using this as a basis, do some quick math and in your query add to the
>   WHERE clause removing any locations that are outside the 'box' that is
>   created by adding the buffer zone with the assumption of 1' lat & 6'
>   long.

Mmmm, "do some quick math" says Patrick. I have failed to do the maths correctly after a few days.

My class is hanging on in there and seems to work for 10km. However, I am failing to make it work with any other distance.

First I moved to seconds, so 10km is:

```
on the latitude is equal to 60 seconds
on the longitude is equal to 360 seconds
```

This worked fine.

However, I then tried 5km is:

```
on the latitude is equal to 30 seconds
on the longitude is equal to 180 seconds
```

This did not work.

Can you explain why this approach does not work for 5km (and other distances I have tried)?

Below is my class code. Clearly the switch is rubbish. Any help appreciated.

```
class coords 
{
/*
    Calculate a bounding box from a decimal coordinate and distance.
    The public vars are populated with minimum and maximum longitudes and latitudes which define the boundary.
*/
    public $dec_lat_min;
    public $dec_lat_max;
    public $dec_lng_min;
    public $dec_lng_max;

    function init($dec_lat, $dec_lng, $dist) 
    { 
        // This switch is a terrible way to allow multiple distances.

        // 10km = 1 min lat = 60 sec lat
        // 10km = 6 min lng = 360 sec lng

        // 5km = 30 sec lat
        // 5km = 180 sec lng

        // 1km = 6 sec lat
        // 1km = 36 sec lat

        // 500m = 3 sec lat
        // 500m = 18 sec lat

        switch($dist)
        {
            case 10: // 10km
                $sec_diff_lat = 60;
                $sec_diff_lng = 360;
                break;
            case 5: // 5km
                $sec_diff_lat = 30;
                $sec_diff_lng = 180;
                break;
            case 1: // 1km
                $sec_diff_lat = 6;
                $sec_diff_lng = 36;
                break;
            default: // 500m
                $sec_diff_lat = 3;
                $sec_diff_lng = 18;
                break;  
        }

        // Convert lat to DMS
        $dms_lat = $this->dec2dms($dec_lat);

        // Allow for western hemisphere (ie negative)
        $dms_lat['hem'] == '-' ? $h = -1 : $h = 1;

        // Populate min and max latitudes
        $this->dec_lat_min = $this->dms2dec($dms_lat['deg'],$dms_lat['min'],$dms_lat['sec']+(-1 * $sec_diff_lat * $h),$dms_lat['hem']);
        $this->dec_lat_max = $this->dms2dec($dms_lat['deg'],$dms_lat['min'],$dms_lat['sec']+($sec_diff_lat * $h),$dms_lat['hem']);

        $dms_lng = $this->dec2dms($dec_lng);

        $dms_lng['hem'] == '-' ? $h = -1 : $h = 1;

        $this->dec_lng_min = $this->dms2dec($dms_lng['deg'],$dms_lng['min'],$dms_lng['sec']+(-1 * $sec_diff_lng * $h),$dms_lng['hem']);
        $this->dec_lng_max = $this->dms2dec($dms_lng['deg'],$dms_lng['min'],$dms_lng['sec']+($sec_diff_lng * $h),$dms_lng['hem']);

    }

    function dec2dms($d) 
    {
        $d = (string)$d;

        // got dashes?
        if ($d[0] == "-") {
            $hem = '-';
            $dVal = substr($d,1);
        } else {
            $hem = '';
            $dVal = $d;
        }

        // degrees = degrees
        $dVals = explode('.', $dVal);
        $dmsDeg = $dVals[0];

        // * 60 = mins
        $dRemainder = ('0.'.$dVals[1]) * 60;
        $dmsMinVals = explode('.', $dRemainder);
        $dmsMin = $dmsMinVals[0];

        // * 60 again = secs
        $dMinRemainder = ('0.'.$dmsMinVals[1]) * 60;
        $dmsSec = round($dMinRemainder);

        return array("deg"=>$dmsDeg,"min"=>$dmsMin,"sec"=>$dmsSec, "hem"=>$hem);
    }

    function dms2dec($deg,$min,$sec,$hem) 
    {
        // find decimal latitude
        $d = $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
        $d = $hem.$d;

        return $this->round100000($d);
    }

    function round100000($v) 
    {
        return round($v * 100000) / 100000;
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 well explained question / problem

Comment: Can you give an example of the table structure you have please?

Comment: As I am experimenting the table is on mySQL: id (INT Autoincrement), description (text), lng (FLOAT(10,6)), lat (FLOAT(10,6)).

Comment: I did not pursue this approach. Instead I decided to bite the bullet and use Postgres+Postgis which is working out fantastically well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer noted you really want to use the Haversine Formula which takes into account the users latitude.

Haversine Formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

This other answer has a ton of great resources to accomplish this in PHP or SQL:

[MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Comment: Thanks very much. The page you link to has great info.

Answer (score 1):

> 10 km in a straight line is: on the longitude is equal to ~6 minutes

The distance to longitude ratio is not a constant - it depends on the the user's latitude. You can use this function for the longitude difference:

```
function distanceToLng($distance,$latDeg) {
    $latRad = $latDeg / 180 * M_PI;
    $R = 6371;
    return atan2(1*sin($distance/$R)*cos($latRad), cos($distance/$R) - sin($latRad)*sin($latRad)) * (180 / M_PI);
}
```

The formula is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222382/get-lat-long-given-current-point-distance-and-bearing) question.

You can calculate latitude difference from a given distance using something like this:

```
$lngDeg = $distanceInKm/6371 * 180 / M_PI
```

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped to keep things simple (and approximate). However, I will now embrace the maths and do it properly.