# Query in google maps

Tags: ajax, google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a page where the user enters me a place,I search this place, I search all the objects in my db that belong to that place and I also search all those who are within a mile of that place. I have already created the structure that allows me to look for a place with auto-completion and point on the map with this code:

```
function initialize() {
    var myCoordsLenght = 6;
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.018151,8.956521),
    zoom: 17
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));


  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });


  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){

    document.getElementById('latitude').value= evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(myCoordsLenght);
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(myCoordsLenght);

});




  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),

    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);



    document.getElementById('latitude').value= place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();


    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="type-selector" class="controls">

      <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label>
    <input id="latitude" type="text" value="" />
    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
    <input id="longitude" type="text" value="" />


    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But at this point how do I run a query that will return me the desired objects and update the map?

Thanks to all

Comment: Please define *search all the objects in my db that belong to that place*. To query your DB for places within a specific range, please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21043061/1238965 Your question should also be tagged with your backend language and the DB you use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Great Circle Distance (Haversine formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula)

Comment: possible duplicate of [radius search by latitude / longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628794/radius-search-by-latitude-longitude)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radius Search using postcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905618/radius-search-using-postcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the bounds of the circle object that you have drawn on the map (which is unfortunately a rectangle). Pass this to your server side, and query the database using something like:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE lat BETWEEN a AND c AND lng between b AND  d
```

Where a and b are you top left coordinates and c and d are your bottom right. ([more information available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834772/get-all-records-from-mysql-database-that-are-within-google-maps-getbounds)).

Now that you have all objects within your bounding box you will need to pass them back to your front-end and determine whether or not they are within your radius. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12383682/1856970) for more information, and you're done!